# Does randomUUID give a unique id?

Tags: java, random, uuid

I am trying to create session tokens for my REST API. Each time the user logs in, I am creating a new token by

```
UUID token = UUID.randomUUID();
user.setSessionId(token.toString());
Sessions.INSTANCE.sessions.put(user.getName(), user.getSessionId());
```

However, I am not sure how to protect against duplicate sessionTokens.

For example: Can there be a scenario when user1 signs in and gets a token `87955dc9-d2ca-4f79-b7c8-b0223a32532a` and user2 signs in and **also** gets a token `87955dc9-d2ca-4f79-b7c8-b0223a32532a`?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `randomUUID()` doesn't collide very often.

Comment: Even if the chances are very low, why not append an epoch timestamp to the UUID ? That would reduce the chance of collision even more than it already is.

Comment: @Amroelaswar Then you should just be using [Version 1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) (a point in space and time) or Version 2 UUIDs rather than Version 4 (random).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you get a UUID collision, go play the lottery next.

From Wikipedia:

> Randomly generated UUIDs have 122 random bits. Out of a total of 128
> bits, four bits are used for the version ('Randomly generated UUID'),
> and two bits for the variant ('Leach-Salz').
>
> With random UUIDs, the
> chance of two having the same value can be calculated using
> probability theory (Birthday paradox). Using the approximation
>
> `p(n)\approx 1-e^{-\tfrac{n^2}{{2x}}}`
>
> these are the probabilities of an
> accidental clash after calculating n UUIDs, with x=2122:
>
> n probability
> 68,719,476,736 = 236  0.0000000000000004 (4 × 10−16)
> 2,199,023,255,552 = 241   0.0000000000004 (4 × 10−13)
> 70,368,744,177,664 = 246  0.0000000004 (4 × 10−10)
>
> To put these numbers into perspective,
> the annual risk of someone being hit by a meteorite is estimated to be
> one chance in 17 billion, which means the probability is about
> 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11), equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of > UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate. In
> other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for
> the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate
> would be about 50%. The probability of one duplicate would be about
> 50% if every person on earth owns 600 million UUIDs.

Comment: And what a about a cluster environment ?

Comment: The original question was in the context of identifiers for a REST api. If you're generating "tens of trillions" of sessions in your api, yes, then collisions might be a concern, but I'd wager you'll have other problems first.

Comment: "the annual risk of someone being hit by a meteorite....." is not a guarantee => In 2016 one man has been killed by a meteorite

Comment: What about generating uuid as the name for files that are being stored in a aws s3 cluster?

Comment: Years ago I used a random uuid for the unique key in a database table. Within the first week I got a collision. Random UUIDs are not totally random and cannot guarantee that a collision will not occur.

Comment: TLDR: `UUID#randomUUID()` generates a **statistically unique** UUID. Which is not the same thing as **unique**. Also, the copy and paste-ness of this answer is making my eyes bleed. Please format the math...

Comment: I remember having this debate once in the presence of a couple of hardware designers. They were quite bemused that we were worried about failure probabilities of 10^-16 or so, pointing out that electromagnetic interference makes the hardware far less reliable than this.

Answer (score 16):

Since a UUID has a finite size, there is no way for it to be unique across all of space and time.

If you need a UUID that is guaranteed to be unique within any reasonable use case, you can use Log4j 2's Uuid.getTimeBasedUuid(). It is guaranteed to be unique for about 8,900 years so long as you generate less than 10,000 UUIDs per millisecond.

Answer (score 8):

Oracle UUID document. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html

They use this algorithm from the The Internet Engineering Task Force. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

A quote from the abstract.

> A UUID is 128 bits long, and can **guarantee**    uniqueness across
>   space and time.

While the abstract claims a guarantee, there are only `3.4 x 10^38` combinations. [CodeChimp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1278839/codechimp)

Comment: guarantee is a strong word.

Comment: That is a quote from the abstract of the algorithm used.  Not my words.

Comment: That would be `(2^128)-1` possible values, or 340,282,366,920,938,463,463,374,607,431,768,211,455.  Still, it is "possible" for there to be a collision, but you would have a 1 in (2^128)-1 chance of that happening, baring the algorithm used was decent.  That's not a very good chance.

Comment: Still, I would not use the word "guarantee", and I would consider that abstract to be incorrect in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

From `UUID.randomUUID()` Javadoc:

> Static factory to retrieve a type 4 (pseudo randomly generated) UUID. The UUID is generated using a cryptographically strong pseudo random number generator.

It's random and therefore a collision will occur, definitely, as confirmed others in comments above/below that detected collisions very early. **Instead of a version 4 (random based) I would advice You to use version 1 (time based).**

*Possible solutions:*

**1) UUID utility from Log4j**

You can use 3rd party implementation from Log4j `UuidUtil.getTimeBasedUuid()` that is based on the current timestamp, measured in units of 100 nanoseconds from October 10, 1582, concatenated with the MAC address of the device where the UUID is created. Please see package `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util` from artifact [log4j-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core).

**2) UUID utility from FasterXML**

There is also 3rd party implementation from FasterXML `Generators.timeBasedGenerator().generate()` that is based on time and MAC address, too. Please see package `com.fasterxml.uuid` from artifact [java-uuid-generator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.uuid/java-uuid-generator).

**3) Do it on your own**

Or You can implement Your own using constructor `new UUID(long mostSigBits, long leastSigBits)` from core Java. Please see following very nice explanation [Baeldung - Guide to UUID in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-uuid) where October 15, 1582 (actually, very famous day) is used in implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be *absolutely 100% dead certain* that there will be NO duplicates, just make a TokenHandler. All it needs is a synchronized method that generates a random UUID, loops over every single one that has been created (not very time efficient, sure, but if the token is to be used as a **session** ID then a good data structure is all that is needed to make this very fast still), and if the token is unique then the handler saves it before returning it.

This is seriously overkill though. Would be easier to just follow the suggestion of having your tokens be a combination of UUID and timestamp. If you use System.nanotime in addition to UUID I don't see there being a collision at any time in eternity.